# Is there a way to postpone execution of a target in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to run several tests of my code, like so:

make test1 test2 test3 test4 ...

In total, this takes multiple hours, so I want to run this at night, so I can check the results in the morning.

It so happens that I need some licenses for those tests. At midnight, our license server is shortly rebooted (only takes about a minute). If it so happens that e.g. test3 starts executing while the license server is rebooting, it errors and doesn't execute the test. Which is annoying.

A possible solution I'm looking into is whether it's possible check the time before you start executing a test. If it's e.g. between 23:58 and 00:02, wait 5 minutes or whatever. I just want to avoid starting a test while rebooting. If the test is already running and then the server is rebooted, there is no issue.

I tried googling it, but I didn't really find anything related to that, so my hopes are quite low.

Comment: As the answer shows you can do whatever you want in your recipe, you don't need make to implement something.  IMO the best solution is for whatever facility is retrieving the key, to know that it might sometimes not succeed and to retry for some amount of time if the first attempt fails.  this way you will not slow down the testing any more than required.

Comment: That would indeed be preferable, but I have no control over that. It's all done in a bought tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something you need to do in Make itself.  Just add a command at the beginning of each rule that needs the licence.  If we need it a lot, use a variable to save writing it many times.

```
avoid_midnight = if date +%H%M | grep -qE '235[89]|000[01]'; then sleep 5m; fi

test1.results: test1
    $(avoid_midnight)
    ./< >&@
```

Comment: Good thinking. After a quick test, it seems to have the wanted effect :)

Comment: I've just kept your suggested 5-minute sleep.  If you want something cleverer, then I have a very simple [`sleep-until`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204673/75307) script that you could use to reduce the amount of sleeping.  Or you could write something that polls the licence server.